# Excel - Show content as HTML for transfer to Lotus Notes

Tags: html, excel, lotus-notes

I have an Excel VBA script that generates an HTML document (no JS or CSS involved) based on spreadsheet values. I have the HTML contents stored as a string inside a cell.

I'd like to have this content to be sent as an HTML email from Lotus Notes. Right now, I have to do the following:
1. Copy the cell contents to an .html file
2. Open the .html file in Chrome
3. Copy the contents from Chrome
4. Paste the contents to Lotus Notes Composer

My objective here is to trim down this workflow to reduce the number of steps.

The ideal case would be for me to be able to copy and paste directly from Excel to Lotus Notes but all I can manage to get is some table cell instead of an HTML-formated block pasted.

The second-most ideal case would be for the cell to open a browser tab with the HTML content. I would like to avoid doing server-side scripting for portability so POST, GET, and etc are largely out of question.

Any advice on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your objective to send an email automatically without user interviention? Or is your objective to open up an email message in the Lotus Note client, populate the body of the message with HTML, maybe populate some of the other fields (e.g., To, Subject, etc.() and then let the user do the actual sending?

Comment: The second approach is what I want. The reason being that it is still necessary for someone to manually check over the contents as a last step.

Answer (score 0):

The Notes client's UI isn't expecting raw HTML as input, so I think you're going to have fair amount of work to do in order to get around that. Most likely you're going to have to use the [Notes OLE classes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_USING_NOTES_CLASSES_IN_VISUAL_BASIC.html) to create a draft message (i.e., a NotesDocument without a SentDate or DeliveredDate item) in the user's mail file, give it an HTML body (using the NotesMimeXXX classes, and give it a unique subject, then save the draft, use NotesDatabase.getView to open the Drafts view, walk through the view until you find the entry with the correct subject, open that entry as a NotesDocument, and finally use the NotesUIWorkspace.EditDocument method with the correct NotesDocument argument to open for edit in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the spreadsheet is, and what values you want from it, my solution would be to write a LotusScript routine behind an action button in Memo form.

The purpose of this code would be to open the Excel file using OLE, read the necessary data and build a NotesRichTextItem in a temporary document.  Then Save the temp document, and close the Excel sheet. Use the undocumented "NotesUIDocument.ImportItem" method to copy the saved message to your current notes document, then delete the temp document.  Done.

Once you've opened the worksheet in OLE the code will be very similar to your macro, but you won't be able to use ActiveDocument or Application etc, and you'll have to declare or replace any Excel VBA constants you've used.

Phil

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve what you want. I would use OLE/COM:

In your Excel- Script just write code like the following:

```
Dim ws As Object
Dim ses as Object
Dim mailDb as Object
Dim memo as Object
Dim uidoc as Object

REM "These lines will start the Lotus Notes- Client if it is not already started"
Set ws = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Set ses = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")

REM "you might need these lines to get the Lotus Notes Window in focus"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

REM "In version 9 the windowtitle will be different..."
WshShell.AppActivate ("Lotus Notes")

REM "Get the users maildatabase"
Set mailDb = ses.GetDatabase("","")
Call mailDb.OpenMail

REM "Create a new mail"
Set memo = mailDb.CreateDocument
Call memo.ReplaceItemValue( "Form", "Memo" )

REM "Open the mail in frontend"
Set uidoc = ws.EditDocument(True,memo)

REM "Switch to Body field"
Call uidoc.GotoField( "Body" )

REM "Here comes the magic..."
Call uidoc.Import( "HTML File", "C:\Temp\yourHtml.html" )
```

You need to write the html code to the filesystem (temporary, delete it afterwards), but that way you do not need to take care for conversion to mime, etc...